# Use Python to find and remove duplicate text in a collection of files

Tags: python, algorithm, text

I have a collection of 40-50 text files that contain markdown. Some of them contain duplicate words, sentences, and paragraphs. I'm looking for a script/algorithm to scan the files and help me identify matches (or near matches). Where can I find such a thing? Searching for this type of thing online yielded results for other types of problems, but not this one. Would appreciate any clues to help me narrow my search...

Comment: Your problem statement is not very specific. Do you want duplicate words, sentences, or paragraphs? Do you want matches or near matches? Different answers here lead to different algorithms.

Comment: Perhaps consider including some of the online results you found and tell us how those other types of problems differ, or may be similar, to this problem -- this would help us narrow down your problem so we can help

Comment: Thanks @Rory_Daulton To be more specific, I'm looking for a script/algorithm to scan multiple files and identify duplicate sequences of words that vary in length from approximately 7 to 70 words. It would be nice (optional) to identify near matches (that contain up to 15% variations). My previous search results were completely irrelevant to this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, a simple brute forces can solve all of your problems. But you should consider another algorithms depend on your requirement (timing, memory,...): Boyer–Moore, Rabin–Karp string search algorithm, Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of answer I need to better define the problem domain and continue searching. I'll post more information here about what I find.